# click 'onclick' button in codeception

Tags: javascript, automation, codeception

There are several button like this,, can some one please help

```
<div class="widgetBox">
<a onclick="javascript:addToDashboard(28,'widget_email');" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <div class="widget-icon"><img alt="" src="/themes/bravo/img/ico-widget.png" style="width:52px;"></div>
    <div class="widget-data">
        <h1>Email</h1>
        <p>Email</p>
    </div>
</a>

<div class="widgetBox">
<a onclick="javascript:addToDashboard(22,'widget_lead_distribution');" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <div class="widget-icon"><img alt="" src="/themes/bravo/img/ico-widget.png" style="width:52px;"></div>
    <div class="widget-data">
        <h1>Lead Distribution</h1>
        <p>Lead Distribution</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

i want to click specifically on Lead Distribution without using Xpath,, because each time the widget box is accessed it changes the button position,, i feel link if i can access

```
<a onclick="javascript:addToDashboard(22,'widget_lead_distribution');" href="javascript:void(0);">
```

this line it can workout for me but i am unable to click on 'onclick'

Answer (score 1):

You don't click on `onclick` but on the a element. It will trigger onclick method. You have to use acceptance tests to test javascript in codeception. Documentation is [here](http://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests).

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->click('.widgetBox a');
```